# Is there a way to see who called the nodejs controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js

We got a lot of pages/sites calling different nodejs controllers.

Example:

```
//
// Get template data
//
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: globalSetting.serverURL + 'getMailTemplate',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: {
        users:       $scope.vm.user,
        booking:     $scope.vm.booking
    }
}).then((response) => {
    // whatever
}
```

Is there a way for the controller to see where the call came from?

Which page called or which URL or which user or??

Comment: you added just `js` code, but not `node js`, you can check the `req` object and u ll get may details from it

Comment: Thanks Sravan I will try and do that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to a req object in Node.js express you can get some useful caller details from it, for example IP address, location etc.

```
const express = require('express');
const geoip = require('geoip-lite');

var app = express();
app.set('trust proxy', true);

function getCallerDetails(req) {

    const geo = geoip.lookup(req.ip);

    const result = {
        ip: req.ip,
        browser: req.headers["user-agent"],
        language: req.headers["accept-language"],
        country: (geo ? geo.country: "Unknown"),
        region: (geo ? geo.region: "Unknown"),
        position: (geo ? geo.ll: "Unknown")
    }

    return result;
}

app.get('/getcallerdetails', function(req, res){


    let result = getCallerDetails(req);

    console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(result.headers));
    console.log('IP Address: ' + JSON.stringify(result.ip));
    console.log("Browser/User-Agent: " + result.browser);
    console.log("Language: " + result.language);
    console.log("Country: " + result.country);
    console.log("Region: " + result.region);

    console.log(result);

    res.status(200);
    res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Terry thats exactly what I needed!! - Thanks a bunch.  (wonder why people downvote you question, with it was a legit question with a legit answer?!?)